# Get the position of a view just after an addView()

Tags: android

Everything is in the title. I need to add the view at some point in my relativeLayout but not necessary at the OnCreate method. What I want to do is adding a view when the user click on the RelativeLayout, no problem for that. But I need to know the position of this view as soon as possible after I used addView method. Currently I'm using postDelayed but I need to put a high value to be sure that it is displayed before taking the position of the view. I tried using post but didn't work very well so that's why i use a delayed value. I also tried something with treeObserver some time ago but maybe i used it wrong I don't know because it did not work.

Edit:
Here I create the layout param.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams laoutparam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    laoutparam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

Here I create my custom view and add the layoutparam to it:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lol);

    CustView view = new Bubble(getApplicationContext(), "Press this button", button);
    bubble.setLayoutParams(laoutparam);
```

And then in the constructor of my custom RelativeLayout I do an addView(view).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think in your relativelayout you have to specify the position of the view before adding it. If not specified the view is added at the position (0,0). If you specify the position then you know the position. What's the problem? I don't see it.

Comment: What I do is that after instanciating my view I create a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams then give it to my view and finally add my view to my relativeLayout.  But it still doesnt works.

Comment: Can you show us some code please?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to edit

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you with getting view location: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view-in-android

Example:

```
int loc[]=new int[2];
yourView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
int x=loc[0];
int y=loc[1];
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions. Links are prone to be broken after a while.